# jQuery getJSON cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get the data with jQuery Cross Domain (on github)..  but without success!
I read that i must make a request jsonp, but I do not understand what is wrong..

http://jsfiddle.net/jzjVh/

Chrome interprets the file as Javascript..
IE9 except a warning because the file "was blocked due to mime type mismatch"..
I do not even understand if there is a difference from .txt and .json.

Comment: You should research for _ajax Cross Domain_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

And here we go again...
You are fighting with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy.

[image]
While

[image]

Possible solution will be using  a local proxy like http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

[image]

Comment: You can publish your answer step by step, as long as the initial answer has a value, _"You are fighting with Same origin policy"_ doesn't fit the criteria IMHO. And anyway, your answer even in the current state is a links proxy, you should try to improve it.

Comment: @gdoron: Went on some other site in between so posted incomplete answer. I have updated my answer. Thank you.

Comment: It still should be a comment and not an answer. If you only give him reading assignment **=> comment**.

Comment: @gdoron: I have update my answer again. I think adding images give better understanding. It should be in comment but images cant be added there so..

Comment: Reverted the downvote. Good luck! thanks for improving your post! we all benefit from it!

Comment: @gdoron: Thanks and will surely keep this in mind. Alsothanks for comment with downvote it helps to know the reason behind reward :)

Comment: Ooook! I understand why it did not works..
But, I do not understand what it refers the jQuery docs for the parameter "crossDomain" in $.ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: (Copied from same URL , Look at the bold part). `If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for example, SERVER SIDE REDIRECTION to another domain.`