# Cross-Subdomain Requests

Tags: javascript, html, nginx

I have two URLs:

One is the application URL = http://domain.com/app
One is the application API URL = http://api.domain.com/

How can I get the application to be able to request things from the api at a different subdomain.

I have already tried putting Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * on both sides with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: It might help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11072639/705773

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two servers (not the client) need to send the following headers:

1. Access-Control-Allow-Origin : Decide which origin could call into the server
2. Access-Control-Allow-Methods : The method that is allowed to access the resource (GET or POST)
3. Access-Control-Max-Age : How long the cache is held

You could inspect the headers returned from the server (using Firebug or others) if the servers are supporting cross origin resource sharing.

If you can't modify the two servers to add the headers, one other possibility to set up a proxy that sit between your request and two servers. This proxy could add the headers if you need to access them

If you own admin right to the servers, [this CORS page](http://enable-cors.org/) shows how to add the headers in various platforms.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

set the cookie domain to `.domain.com` and you should be all set.. This is what I have done in my application..

Comment: There are currently no cookies being set.

Comment: I will be. Currently developing an application.